# Debugging Rails with Passenger and Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

Some of the threads I was following seem old, so maybe what I am trying to do has been superseded by something else--if that is the case, please let me know!

I just reinstalled a Rails app on a new server, but this time am using Apache and Passenger. Rails version 1.8.7, Apache2, and Passenger on a Ubuntu 12.04 server. I would like to still have a debugger, so I tried following this thread:

http://chrisadams.me.uk/2009/04/28/how-to-set-up-a-debugger-with-mod_railspassenger 
http://duckpunching.com/passenger-mod_rails-for-development-now-with-debugger
 (the original article)

I'm pretty sure I followed this exactly, and my files are correct. But I am getting two discrepencies. First, when I refresh my webpage, my site does not hang (as stated on the duckpunching page)...second, when I put in:

```
rdebug -c
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/cli/ruby-debug.rb:109:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/cli/ruby-debug.rb:109:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/cli/ruby-debug.rb:109:in `start_client'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/bin/rdebug:336
    from /usr/bin/rdebug:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rdebug:23
```

So I feel like my terminal is not automatically connecting somehow? As I stated, I can't really find updated information online about this problem, so any help is appreciated in either making this work (console-type debugging for Apache / Passenger, like what I had with WEBrick) or current best-practices.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the debug.txt file is being created and deleted as is should be? Also did you modify development.rb or production.rb?

Comment: I am using the RailsEnv development setting, so I modified development.rb to include, at the bottom (I included the path directly since RAILS_ROOT variable was giving me an error--I guess it's not defined on my system): 

if File.exists?(File.join('~/www/glp','tmp','debug.txt'))
  require 'ruby-debug'
  Debugger.wait_connection = true
  Debugger.start_remote
  File.delete(File.join('~/www/glp','tmp','debug.txt'))
end

There is also a debug.txt file under /tmp, but it is empty (and not being deleted as it should be?).

Comment: `File.join('~/www/glp','tmp','debug.txt')` Could be tricky as `~` refers to the home of the user the application is run under. This is usually the owner of the config.ru file. Also, use `Rails.root` instead of `RAILS_ROOT` when working with rails 3 (are you?).

Comment: Thanks! That worked (Rails.root instead of path)! Yes to Rails 3 by the way. Haha, any way to vote for your comments as a "solution" to my question and give you due credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether

```
File.join('~/www/glp','tmp','debug.txt')
```

refers to the correct path as it is evaluated as the owner of config.ru.